# Slope function of a curve

Tags: integration

I have a question I am having trouble answering:

The slope function of a curve is: $$\frac{dy}{dx}=ux+k$$

u and k are constants.

The curve passes through $(0,-1)$ and $(2,-5)$

At $(2,-5)$ the slope equals $1$.

How do I get the equation?

I have tried integrating and pluging the two above points in and trying to solve for u and k but I end up getting the integration constant $c=-1$ and $k=2-u$  I then plug this into the integrated slope function: $$\frac{ux^2}{2} + kx -1$$

but I don't get the correct answer.

Could someone point out where I am going wrong wrong and how to correct it.

Comment: you meant you first "equation" to read $\frac{dy}{dx}  = ux + k$, right?

Comment: Yes, sorry I did

Comment: It looks like you solved for $c$ correctly, but I imagine you made an algebra mistake somewhere on the way to solving for $k=-5$ and $u=3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With

$y' = ux + k$

we have in general

$y = \frac{1}{2}ux^2 + kx + c$,

for some constant $c$.   Plugging in the point $(0,  -1)$ yields

$c = -1$;

plugging in $(2, -5)$ gives

$2(u + k) = -4$

and, last but not least, plugging $x = 2$, $y' = 1$ into the slope equation gives

$2u + k = 1$.

Then

$2k= -4 - 2u = -4 - (1 - k)$,

whence

$k = -5$;

and

$u = 3$

immediately follows.

Hope this helps.  Cheers.

Comment: Thanks, This is perfect, I see my mistake

Comment: @user2352274:  Glad to be of service!

Answer (score 2):

From $\frac{dy}{dx}=ux+k$ you have $y=\frac{ux^{2}}{2}+kx+c$. The
three pieces of information yield the equations
\begin{align*}
-1 & =0u+0k+1c\\
-5 & =2u+2k+1c\\
1 & =2u+1k+0c.
\end{align*}
You can describe this by the matrix equation
$$
M\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{b}
$$
where
$$
M=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 0 & 1\\
2 & 2 & 1\\
2 & 1 & 0
\end{array}\right]
$$
and
$$
\mathbf{b}=\left[\begin{array}{c}
-1\\
-5\\
+1
\end{array}\right].
$$
Note that the way I've written it,
$$
\mathbf{x}=\left[\begin{array}{c}
u\\
k\\
c
\end{array}\right].
$$
Solving,
$$
\mathbf{x}=M^{-1}\mathbf{b}=\left[\begin{array}{c}
+3\\
-5\\
-1
\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{c}
u\\
k\\
c
\end{array}\right].
$$
This is equivalent to going through and solving each equation in terms
of one of the independent variables.

Comment: Could you write it as individual equations please, it is just a bit clearer for me as I know what the answer should be.  Thanks

Comment: In that case, just see @Adriano's answer.

Answer (score 2):

You solved for $c$ correctly, but you made a mistake with $k$. Note that when you plug in the point $(2, -5)$, you should get:
\begin{align*}
\frac{u(2)^2}{2} + k(2) - 1 &= -5 \\
2u+ 2k &= -4 \\
u+ k &= -2 \tag{1}\\
\end{align*}

Now since the slope at $(2,-5)$ is $1$, we also know that:
\begin{align*}
\frac{dy}{dx}&=ux+k \\
1 &= u(2) + k \\
-2u - k &= -1 \tag{2}\\
\end{align*}

Adding together $(1)$ and $(2)$ yields:
$$
-u=-3 \iff u = 3
$$
Hence, using $(1)$, we obtain $k = -2-u = -2-(3) = -5$.